# Django 1.11 - Can't edit my model in Admin panel

Tags: django

Please could tell me why I can't modify my model in the admin panel of Django ?

models.py :

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Games(models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, verbose_name="GUID")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="Titre")
    logo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Logo")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Games

# Register your models here.

class GamesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('logo', 'title', 'guid', 'date', 'update')
    list_filter = ('title', 'guid')
    date_hierarchy = 'update'
    ordering = ('date', )
    search_field = ('guid', 'title')

admin.site.register(Games, GamesAdmin)
```

When I'm going to the admin panel, I see all the field of my model, I can also add a new field. But when I want to edit the field, there is no link clickable...

Thanks !

Comment: Usually the first column is clickable

Comment: Oh ok I understand, my first column is empty. Do you know how to make all columns cliquable ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just swap the places of 'logo' and 'title' or 'logo' with any other non-empty column.

```
list_display = ('logo', 'title', 'guid', 'date', 'update')
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, the first column should be clickable and take you to the view to change the object. Even if the column is empty, Django will add a clickable non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`), although you might not spot it until you hover over it and the cursor changes.

You can set [`link_display_links`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) and include a field that is not empty.

```
class GamesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('logo', 'title', 'guid', 'date', 'update')
    list_display_links = ('title',)
```

Alternatively, you could reorder `list_display` so that the first column is not empty.

To make all columns clickable, you would set `list_display_links = list_display`.

Comment: Thanks for your help